# How to implement a global timer in a React application?

Tags: reactjs

I want to implement a timer with pause/resume functionalities which should be accessible at any React component. Each React component can add a new interval within the global timer.

I'll be using Typescript.

For example with this pseudo code:

```
// assume GlobalTimer is the Timer class I need to implement

class MyReactComponent {
  myTimer: <some type from GlobalTimer>

  componentDidMount() {
    this.myTimer = GlobalTimer.addEvent({
      delay: 2000, // 2 seconds
      onEnd: this.onTimerEnd,
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    // either destroy each timer individually
    this.myTimer.destroy();

    // or something more cool but not sure if possible to accomplish:
    // GlobalTimer.getTimersForComponent(this).forEach( (timer) => timer.destroy() );
  }

  onEnd() {
     // called when timer fires
  }
}
```

I want to be able to pause all the timers from all components at once, that's why I need to have this timer implemented at a global level.

I'm not sure if I should use the new Context to accomplish what I want. Any suggestions?

Comment: context api is perfect for this.

Comment: Thanks @BhojendraRauniyar, I wasn't sure if Context would be a good fit as I'm still trying to get familiar with it.

Comment: Either context or just a simple singleton.

Comment: I'm still not sure which way to go. I read that singleton isn't recommended. Is there another approach I might be overseeing?

Answer (score 0):

Use React's Context API

> Context is designed to share data that can be considered “**global**” for a tree of React components, such as the current authenticated user, theme, or preferred language.

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html